# Select is not iteratable error while selecting option of a Dropdown based on user input using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, html-select

I want to take input from user every time the user will input company name.So i am getting this error is there any other way to solve this query?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver as driver
menu = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('BodyContent__company'))
name=input('Enter company name: ')
for option in menu:
    if option.text == name:
        option.select()
    else:
        pass
```

Error:

```
Select is not iteratable
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Select is not iteratable
```

...implies that in your code block you are trying to iterate through a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) of type  `Select`.

---

### Solution

Instead of iterating the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) element you need to iterate through the `Select.options` elements as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver as driver

menu = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('BodyContent__company'))
name=input('Enter company name: ')
for option in menu.options:
    if option.text == name:
        option.click()
    else:
        pass
```